# After graduation did the privileges get rejigged

Tags: discussion

I don't see some of the privileges after the site is graduated. I know as part of Graduation a new set of privileges get applied. 
Just putting this question out so that other users know this has happened.

One would now need more privileges to do things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct.  More rep is required for certain actions:

[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

This meta post has a handy dandy chart showing old vs new.

Comment: Painting of unicorns signed by Joel? Now I have something to aim for!

Comment: Can you explain *golden* in that chart? Is there a level here that will let me correct typos at sites where my rep is is sub-1000 and not get rejected as 'too small a change'?

Comment: I think the 3 columns are Private Beta (2 weeks ish?), Public Beta (Where we have been), and Golden (What we just started).

Answer (score 5):

Each site has a dynamic privilege list.  Here is money's: https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

This shows you each privilege you could get and has a green check box if you have that privilege.

*No mention of unicorns.*